# BitmapFactory.decodeFile return null for the same path

Tags: android, image, bitmap, decode

The problem is , even the path is the same but decodefile function return null sometime when I call the function.

```
public static Bitmap lessResolution(String filePath, int width, int height) {
    int reqHeight = width;
    int reqWidth = height;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    //BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    Log.d("test1","f:" + filePath);
    Log.d("test1","b:" + b);

    return b;
}
```

In success case:

```
02-10 09:28:23.554 22444-22444/? D/test1: f:/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/1486690065.jpg
02-10 09:28:23.554 22444-22444/? D/test1: b:android.graphics.Bitmap@8756c
```

In fail case:

```
02-10 09:29:22.425 22444-22444/? D/test1: f:/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/1486690065.jpg
02-10 09:29:22.425 22444-22444/? D/test1: b:null
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I have a similar code running, but with the BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options); uncommented

Comment: Thanks. uncomment give same result